# In python 3.8.9, how to get just the exception error message, instead of whole Exception tuple

Tags: python

I am trying to do INSERT operation into the DB using this:

```
except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

and, I have an error during INSERT operation to the DB (duplicate username):

```
(1062, "Duplicate entry 'a' for key 'username_UNIQUE'")
```

I would like to get just the error message (`"Duplicate entry 'a' for key 'username_UNIQUE'"`), but I don't know how to take the second field of the tuple. If I try `e[1]` or `e(1)` I just get another error. How do I take this second field from the tuple.

Comment: Without knowing what your specific exception is or even which package you're using, it's impossible to help based on a repr of the generic `Exception` class.

Comment: My best guess here is that the `__str__` function of whatever exception class you are actually catching is returning a tuple instead of a string, so the only solution may be the `str(e)[1]` method you already found.

Comment: @nigh_anxiety I didn't do str(e)[1] but first eval-ed it, and then it recognized it correctly as a tuple. Then, I used the [1] bit. I would love to see a more "normal" or put it like this, a "simpler" solution.

Comment: Maybe `e.args[1]`, but as already warned, make sure that the exception caught is not any exception, but really has 2 args.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: @Vlad mysql is the database.

Comment: @VladimirDespotovic In that case what you have is a reference to IntegrityError (from mysql.connector.errors) so just *print(e.msg)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using:

```
eval(str(e))[1]
```

However, I would like to have a more simple solution, if anyone happens to know. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You are using MySQL. Therefore the exception is an instance of IntegrityError (from mysql.connector.errors).

Therefore:

```
from mysql.connector.errors import IntegrityError

try:
  # execute some SQL here
except IntegrityError as e:
  print(e.msg)
```